# Setting a common attribute for multiple deployments

Tags: kubernetes

I have a number of `.yml` files with deployments and their services and need to set `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` to all of them preferrably from one common place.

Answer (score 1):

Some `yq` with simple `bash` script should do the work

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

ALL_FILES=$(ls | grep yml)

for file in $ALL_FILES; do
  echo "File $file"
  yq -i '.spec += {"progressDeadlineSeconds": "10"}' $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out [kustomize](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#field-name-commonannotations) for doing tasks like this. From the limited information it sounds like `commonAnnotations` might do the trick for your use case, but if not there are other transformers that could like `Patch` or `PatchStrategicMerge`.